# Create a tag for PDFKit on iOS 11

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-request

I didn't find a PDFKit tag for iOS. There is a [pdfkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdfkit) tag, but its description says it's "A Ruby gem for creating PDFs using plain old HTML+CSS".

Can someone create a tag for it?

Comment: For what existing questions? What would the tag info say?

Comment: Ok, I will post the question. And the tag should say, `Display and manipulate PDF documents in your applications.` Here is the detailed link - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit

Comment: No plagiarism please

Comment: [swift][pdfkit] or [ios11][pdfkit] are just fine and doesn't require a new tag to disambiguate.  And already being used by 27 questions.  Consider proposing a tag wiki edit.

Comment: There are [more than a few questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpdfkit%5D+ios) tagged `pdfkit`, but mentioning iOS, and apparently about the iOS framework. Maybe `pdfkit-ios` or `pdfkit-framework`?

Comment: Here is the question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693768/highlightedselections-returns-inconsistent-array-elements-in-pdfkit

Comment: And if you guys think tagging a ruby gems `pdfkit` tag will help people then I'm fine.